# How do I put an apostrophe inside of a DataBound server tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say i have a TextBox control inside of a ListView where the text is DataBound and I want to use TrimStart.  What is the proper way to define the char parameters?  When I enter an apostrophe I get a server tag not well formed error... Example below:

```
<asp:ListView>                                                          <!--here-->
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value").ToString().TrimStart('.',':') %>' />
</asp:ListView>
```

This is a simplified example of what I am really doing.  In my situation I must do this trim in the aspx page.

Comment: Not really an answer, but did you try using double quotes instead of single quotes.  It won't throw an error, but I'm not sure what the implication of using them is (i.e. do they change the char to a string, was it a string already, and does it matter...)

Comment: It looks to my like you're writing your app in VB but you're trying to use C# syntax in your TrimStart method.  See my answer below.

Comment: Hmm why does it look like i'm writing in VB?  Everything is C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your code out of you page and implement `OnDataBinding` for the `TextBox`.  I wish more people would do this as it keeps the markup a lot cleaner and puts the code in the codebehind.

Example:

```
<asp:ListView>                                                          
   <asp:TextBox ID="yourTextBox" runat="server" OnDataBinding="yourTextBox_DataBinding" /> 
</asp:ListView>
```

Then implement it in your code where you don't have to deal with these issues and it will get your 'code' out of the markup:

```
protected void yourTextBox_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)(sender);
    tb.Text = Eval("Value").ToString().TrimStart('.', ':');
}
```

I personally try to put no inline code in my markup when possible if using ASP.NET WebForms.  `OnDataBinding` is one of the least explicitly used events and in my opinion helps to create clean markup and keep all your 'code' in the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Put a *c* behind it:

```
"."c
```

Comment: When I used your method I got the following error: "CS1026: ) expected"

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the MSDN example?  It appears as though it's doing the same thing you're attempting

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx

Copy/Paste this and let us know if it works.

```
<asp:ListView>  
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value").ToString().TrimStart("."c,":"c) %>' />
</asp:ListView>
```

Here is a quote from the MSDN article.  Please note that you need to send an Array, not a string .. IE: `Eval("Value")` should be an array

> The following example uses the TrimStart  method to trim white space and comment characters from lines of source code. The StripComments method wraps a call to TrimStart and passes it a **character array** that contains a space and the comment character, which is an apostrophe ( ' ) in Visual Basic and a slash ( / ) in C#. The TrimStart method is also called to remove leading white space when evaluating whether a string is a comment.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the example in that link.  When I used your method I got the following error: "CS1026: ) expected"

Comment: The example in the msdn link is under the "VB" tab. You need a trailing `c`.  Also you need to make sure that `Eval("Value")` is an array.

Comment: TrimStart will trim those characters from every line in the Array you send.

Comment: I'm very confused.  First, I want to use the TrimStart function that is part of the String class.  I'm not doing anything with arrays.  Second, I am using C# and not VB.  Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as that MSDN article goes, it's asking for an Array (still part of the String class).

Comment: Your example in your original question "appears" to be correct (I'm not a C# guy to be able to confirm), however if you're not sending TrimStart an array, it's probably going to puke on you.  Can you edit your original question with a little more detail as to what you're trying to Trim out of the string?

Comment: The code i have in there is valid C# when put into the code behind.  It does ask for an Array but the method I am using works.  `Eval("Value")` does not need to be an array and i'm not sure it would even parse if it was.  I am trying to trim the . and the : characters

Comment: Can you not just use String.Replace(input,".","") and String.Replace(input, ":","")

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping the single quote.

```
.TrimStart('\'', '.')
```

Comment: I'm not trying to remove a single quote.  I'm trying to remove a . and a :

Comment: My bad.  Try to HTMLEncode it. 

Server.HtmlEncode(yourString)